# Getting items from a folder from SourceForge SVN Project

Tags: vb.net, sourceforge

```
   Function getItems()
        ''# make a reference to a directory
        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("https://ipossum.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/ipossum/")
        Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
        Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

        ''#list the names of all files in the specified directory
        For Each dra In diar1
            ListBox1.Items.Add(dra)
        Next
    End Function
```

That is my code and it did not work. The error was "`Warning 1 Function 'getItems' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used. C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\iPossum\Form1.vb 13 5 iPossum`".

How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To fix the error you're asking about, just change the word `Function` to `Sub`.

However, after you do this you're code still won't work.  You'll have a new error, because the *System.IO directory and file classes only work on the local file system*.  You can't reference a remote https location that way.  You'll need to use System.Net.HttpWebRequest/System.Net.HttpWebResponse or System.Net.WebClient instead, and that means essentially starting from scratch with this code.

---

A very simple example that may or may not work, depending on the https requirement:

```
Dim fileList As String
Using wc As New WebClient
    fileList = wc.DownloadString("https://ipossum.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/ipossum/")
End Using
''# Here you'll have to parse the file names out of this response on your own
```

Comment: I'm not that great with requesting files of any type, if you could, and have the time could you write me the snippet?